# sonarqube plugin can't use jsonp

Tags: json, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I try to write a SonarQube widget plugin which accesses Jenkins build information by jsonp(json with padding).

This is my html file:

```html
<p id="id"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display(data){
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = data.number;
}

</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://MYHOST/job/MYJOB/lastBuild/api/json?jsonp=display"> </script>
```

**the html is running fine on my localhost.**

But when the html built as a widget plugin in my sonarqube server, the jsonp get error.

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (jsonp forbidden; implement jenkins.security.SecureRequester)**

My SonarQube version is 5.6.

Is there any sonarqube web security policy I didn't get it?

Comment: it does not seem to be a problem on SonarQube side but on Jenkins side.

Comment: I have allowed jsonp request on my Jenkins server.
The html work fine on my localhost, even on this website if I use the right url.
But the html can't work when it became a widget plugin in SonarQube.